# printing from file to console and other file

Tags: python, spaces

I'm reading this lines from a file

```
yara_rule1:
   rule match:
   problem:

yara_rule2:
   rule match:
   problem:
```

when I print it into console the spaces before "rule match" and "problem" are omitted .
what is the problem

```
input_data = open(file)
for line in input_data:
    print line.strip()
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the output from the console into your question. Also removing surrounding whitespace is exactly what `strip()` does - in fact, that's the only reason I can imagine you would use it.

Comment: Wow. You're `strip()`ing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes *all* whitespace from both the end *and start* of the string. In other words, it is the `line.strip()` method call that produces a line without the initial whitespace.

If you wanted to remove just the newline, use `str.rstrip()`:

```
print line.rstrip('\n')
```

Compare:

```
>>> '   rule match:\n'.strip()
'rule match:'
>>> '   rule match:\n'.rstrip('\n')
'   rule match:'
```